# Can the Apache SetEnvIf Request_URI variable be decoded in Virtual Host and/or Server config context?

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, environment-variables

When the following `SetEnvIf` directive is in a virtual host directory section or in an `.htaccess` file the `Request_URI` variable is percent decoded.
But when it is not in a `directory` section or `.htaccess` file (i.e. virtual host or server config context) it is not decoded (it remains percent encoded).

What controls/determines this difference?  My guess is that this is a byproduct of having to traverse the file system directory tree.  Because the file system path is not percent encoded.

Is this configurable such that the `Request_URI` Apache `SetEnvIf` variable is percent decoded in the virtual host and/or server config context also?

`SetEnvIf Request_URI "^.*access_logger/counters/(.*)\.gif$" Page_Name_File_Name=$1 log_file log_sql_db validate_cache`

Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Apr  2 2020 13:13:23

Answer (score 0):

> My guess is that this is a byproduct of having to traverse the file system directory tree.

This is a reasonable "guess" since the directives in a server/virtualhost context are processed before the request is mapped to the filesystem.

However, the same does not apply to the `REQUEST_URI` (same name, but different) server variable as used by mod_rewrite and Apache expressions. This is *always* %-decoded, regardless of which context it is being used. The same applies to the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` directive, which is always %-decoded, regardless of context.

> Is this configurable such that the Request_URI Apache SetEnvIf variable is percent decoded in the virtual host and/or server config context also?

Not that I'm aware. This would seem to be a "feature" of mod_setenvif. (Perhaps due to the specific phases in which the module is processed?)

However, you can use mod_rewrite to set the environment variable instead (or as well as). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule access_logger/counters(.*)\.gif$ - [E=Page_Name_File_Name:$1]
```

The `^.*` prefix on the regex is superfluous in this instance.

To set all the environment variables, as per the original `SetEnvIf` directive, you'll need to explicitly set the remaining vars to `1`. For example:

```
RewriteRule access_logger/counters(.*)\.gif$ - [E=Page_Name_File_Name:$1,E=log_file:1,E=log_sql_db:1,E=validate_cache:1]
```